# WCF Authentication on the Internet

Tags: wcf-security

I have a WCF service using the basicHTTP binding. The service will be targeted to be deployed 
in production in a DMZ environment on a Windows Server 2008 64 bit running IIS 7.0 and is not
in an Active Directory domain.

The service will be accessed by a business partner over the Internet with SSL protection. Originally,
I had built the service to use x.509 Message authentication with wsHTTPBinding and after a lot of 
problems I punted and decided to back up and use basicHTTP with UserName authentication.

Result: same exact, obscure error message as I received with certificate mode.

The service works perfectly inside our domain with the exact same authentication but as soon as
I move it to the DMZ I get an error reading: "An unsecured or incorrectly secured fault was received 
from the other party. See the inner FaultException for the fault code and detail".

The inner exception message is: "An error occurred when verifying security for the message."

The services' web config with binding configuration is as follows:

```
  <services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="HSSanoviaFacade.Service1Behavior" name="HSSanoviaFacade.HSSanoviaFacade">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="HSSanoviaFacade.IHSSanoviaFacade" bindingConfiguration="basicHttp">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="https://FULLY QUALIFIED HOST NAME CHANGED TO PROTECT/>
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttp">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
    </security>
     </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="HSSanoviaFacade.Service1Behavior">
     <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="True" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

The test client's configuration that gets the error:

```
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IHSSanoviaFacade" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
                messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None"
                        realm="" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
     <client>
        <endpoint address="https://HOST NAME CHANGED TO PROTECT"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IHSSanoviaFacade"
            contract="MembersService.IHSSanoviaFacade" name="BasicHttpBinding_IHSSanoviaFacade" />
    </client>
```

As mentioned earlier, the service works perfectly on the domain and the production IIS box is not on a domain.
I have been tweaking and pulling my hair out for 2 weeks now and nothing seems to work. If anyone can help I 
would appreciate it. Even a recommendation for a work around for authentication. I'd rather not use a custom
authentication scheme but use built-in SOAP capabilities.

The credentials pass in thru the proxy i.e. proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName and
proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password are valid accounts on both the internal domain in the test 
environment and as a machine account on the DMZ IIS box.

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe not exactly what I wanted but I got it to work. Must be a difference in IIS in a domain versus not.

Here are my changes to the service web config:

```
<security mode="Transport">
  <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
</security>
```

As I understand it, this doesn't pass the credentials in the SOAP header but in the HTTP header which means message level security doesn't work in this scenario. Its all protected by an SSL certificate.